# query that searches array and returns an object element

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have a document that contains the following:

```
    var userSchema = Schema({
    _id: Number,
    fName: String,
    lName: String,
    email: String,
    braintreeflag : {type:Boolean, default: false},
    balance: {type:Number, default: 0},
    braintreeId : {unique:true, type:Number, default:0},
    notificationHubTag: String,
    defaultPaymentMethod: Number,
    braintreeTokens : [{id: Number, token : String}]
});

exports.getDefaultPaymentMethodToken = function(uId,defaultId, res){
    //TODO query
}
```

I want to look in the document where _id : uID and I want to find the array element where id : defaultId and then return the token in this element. Looking on SO, I found what looks like the best solution but it is not tested:

```
User.findOne({_id:uId, 'braintreeTokens.id': defaultId}, {'braintreeTokens.$':1}, function(err,user){
        })
```

Comment: What about if more than one person share same last name?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind:"$employees"},
  {$match:{"employees.lastName":"Doe"}}
])
```

This query will return you one or more documents having `lastName = "Doe"`

Comment: Since you have removed sample MongoDB document, this solution has become almost irrelevant. If you are seeking a different solution, I'd suggest to post another question instead of modifying original one.